# jQuery is() function in TypeScript definition

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm using the jQuery is() function [from here](http://api.jquery.com/is/). The documentation says that it returns a bool. In the TypeScript definition file it has the following for the is() function:

```
is(selector: string): JQuery;
is(func: (index: any) =>any): JQuery;
is(element: any): JQuery;
is(obj: JQuery): JQuery;
```

Am I correct in saying that I just need to change the return type from JQuery to bool to fix this in the definition file?

Comment: Yes, change it. I wouldn't write it as an answer...

Comment: It looks so. What makes you doubt?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: perhaps the fact that it was written by guys from MS (who are experienced and authoritative).

Comment: I questioned this because an is() type of function would always return a bool so I didn't believe anybody would make that type of mistake so I thought it was deliberate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `is` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/is/) seems pretty clear that this is the case.

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

I'm not going to try and second guess the developer that wrote the `jquery.d.ts` definition - it is possible that there is a mistake in the jQuery documentation (it isn't unknown) - but it is also likely that any jQuery functions that return things other than `JQuery` will have been mistakenly defined that way because most jQuery function do return a jQuery object.

I would change the return value to `bool`. I will raise a bug on Codeplex, that way the TypeScript team can either fix it or explain it.